# How to Start/Stop a Windows Service in Safe Mode

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-update

I installed SharePoint on W2K8 64 bit VMWare workstation. I cannot boot up because it freezes as it attempts to install Windows Updates. One error in the log says that Windows Messaging service should be running but I was not able to start this in Safe Mode. Has anyone got some suggestions on how to get my VM back up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved problem be rebuilding VM. Note: one error I made was installing Powershell 2.0 without uninstalling 1.0 - not sure if this contributed to the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is the question about how to start a service in safe mode, or how to resolve your problem booting into Windows in Normal mode?  Have you tried Last Known Good Configuration?

Comment: I was wondering how to start the service in safe mode.